# Designing the metadata with Term store

Tags: term-store

I am in the process of Designing the Metadata for uploading and displaying the documents with a huge number of documents in a library.For this I have created a Term-set with 5 levels in it. How do I create a metadata with 5 levels of term-sets? My term set looks like this.

[image]

Comment: The term set with its terms is the metadata, not really grasping what you are asking?

Comment: I have mentioned the above term-sets and I would like to set up as a document library with the different permissions for each level.

Comment: I think you should update your question to clarify that :)